# Ubuntu Systemclock HWClock jumps 20 seconds and back

Tags: ubuntu, ntp, time

short explained but no idea hot to solve issue:
My Hardware clock (Ubuntu 16.04) is jumping once a minute 20 seconds or so in the future and then back. I have issues with some timestmap comparisation in my database because of that, the issue happens no matter if ntp is enabled/disabled, installed or not installed.

See the following log:

```
user@Server:~$ sudo hwclock --show
Mon 01 May 2017 11:56:27 PM CEST  .975031 seconds
user@Server:~$ sudo hwclock --show
Mon 01 May 2017 11:56:28 PM CEST  .974956 seconds
user@Server:~$ sudo hwclock --show
Mon 01 May 2017 11:56:29 PM CEST  .975890 seconds
user@Server:~$ sudo hwclock --show
Mon 01 May 2017 11:56:30 PM CEST  .975229 seconds
user@Server:~$ sudo hwclock --show
Mon 01 May 2017 11:56:59 PM CEST  .475853 seconds <--- wtf is going on here? (+19 seconds)
user@Server:~$ sudo hwclock --show
Mon 01 May 2017 11:56:33 PM CEST  .974229 seconds <--- now its back to normal
user@Server:~$ sudo hwclock --show
Mon 01 May 2017 11:56:34 PM CEST  .974951 seconds
```

This werid thing happens once per minute. Anybody got an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have NTP running in a VM that's configured to have time managed by the hypervisor?

Comment: Yes, that was it - its running in Hyper-V! Disabled it and now its fine, Thanks!